How do I preserve attributes on multiline XML formatting with XDocument?
I'm working on XML to edit attributes and values. I have an XML node in this format.
<add 
   attribute1="value" 
   attribute2="ghjg" 
   attribute3="ghjg" 
   attribute4="ghjg" 
/>

After changing values on save, it changes to
<add attribute1="value" attribute2="ghjg" attribute3="ghjg" attribute4="ghjg" />

I tried LoadOptions and SaveOptions but none is working.
XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(xmlCondigurationPath,LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

xmlFile.Save(xmlCondigurationPath,SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);


Attributes are suppose to be on same line.  White Spaces are usually ignored with XML.

It's against the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize

I don't think there is any to preserve white space between attributes within a given element node, because there is nothing that could correspond to intra-attribute spacing in the XmlReader.NodeType enumeration.  ...

... The XmlNodeType enum has XmlNodeType.Attribute for an attribute, XmlNodeType.Whitespace for whitespace between markup, and Whitespace.SignificantWhitespace for White space between markup in a mixed content model or white space within the xml:space="preserve" scope.  There's just nothing there corresponding to XmlNodeType.AttributeWhiteSpace for insignificant whitespace inside a given markup tag.  Which is probably because intra-attribute spacing is never significant.

Is your actual requirement that you need to compare two XML documents, and differences in attribute spacing is messing you up?  If so, maybe see How would you compare two XML Documents?.

Use XmlWriter with XmlWriterSettings.
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { NewLineOnAttributes = true, Indent = true };
using var writer = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml", settings);
xDocument.Save(writer);


How i can use it with XDocument to update the existing file?
